# Can't build the cocos2dx sample HelloCpp project

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, cocos2d-iphone, android-ndk

I just started to investigate Cocos2d-x, after a struggling for a long time following the flow on the [website](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki). From the "Getting started", I followed step by step to Linux Environment.

- I have downloaded Cocos2d-x-2.2 from the official page and now I nowhere can find "./create-linux-eclipse-project.sh"

Then I go to "How to run HelloWorld and tests on linux" as the suggestion.

- This time, I nowhere can find "HelloWorld" sample in my downloaded packaged.

After a bunch of confusion, I come to "How to create a new game" once again

- I nowhere can find "./create-multi-platform-projects.py"

I get really confused! The document does not match well, and then one more step I try to build a sample with my experience just to save any idea that can help me to understand this situation.

I import the sample project HelloCpp.

I run build_native.sh in /samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android folder then I comeback to eclipse and build.

Then here it gives this error:

> Errors occurred during the build.
>   Errors running builder 'Integrated External Tool Builder' on project 'HelloCpp'.
>   Exception occurred executing command line.
>   Cannot run program "/home/dudu/android-ndk-r9b/ndk-build.cmd" (in directory "/home/dudu/cocos2d-x-2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android"): error=13, Permission denied

I am really struggling with the tutorials of Cocos2d. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the investigation on cocos2d-x too. The docs really poor and too outdated to misleading.

For your error, first make sure you have write permission on those directories.

If that's not about write permission, then try ndk-r8e or earlier ndk version. I reckon (It seems they have mentioned somewhere but I can't find now) the current version (cocos2d-x-2.2) doesn't well support ndk-r9 or ndk-r9b

Hope it helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

In your computer there may be not permission to access the drive in which your project exist.
The you should give full control to that drive or take ownership of drive by using ownership software.